# How to store secret variable such as shared access token in dot env?

Tags: linux, bash, dotenv

I am trying to store my secret of type SharedAccessToken in dot env
however I am getting an error. Below is my code sample

### .env file

```
accessToken=SharedAccessToken integration&ndkngkdhkgkdfbknbkjbkfjkotnfkobfnokbn+%^&$&^%#$^&^
```

---

when I try to load the variable into the environment, it shows in bash shell something like below:

`` .env:5: parse error near `&' ``

Looks like it's unable to parse special characters like &, ^, spaces, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your token under double quotes (" ") and it should work,
I have tested the same in my system and its working.

```
Rahuls-Linux ~/test $ cat .env 
accessToken="SharedAccessToken integration&ndkngkdhkgkdfbknbkjbkfjkotnfkobfnokbn+%^&$&^%#$^&^"
Rahuls-Linux ~/test $ echo $accessToken
SharedAccessToken integration&ndkngkdhkgkdfbknbkjbkfjkotnfkobfnokbn+%^&$&^%#$^&^
Rahuls-Linux ~/test $
```